# How do I use gstreamer as external source for a stream in go2rtc?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, gstreamer

The documentation [here](https://github.com/AlexxIT/go2rtc#source-exec) of the `exec` source in go2rtc hints that it is possible to use gstreamer as input for a camera stream using pipe to stdout.

With gstreamer I use `filesink location=/dev/stdout` to pipe to stdout:

```yaml
streams:
    mygstreamer: |
        exec:gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videorate ! \
        clockoverlay time-format="%D %H:%M:%S" ! \
        videoconvert ! video/xraw,format=I420,width=${RESOLUTION_X},height=${RESOLUTION_Y},framerate=${FRAMERATE}/1 ! \
        x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1000 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! \
        filesink location=/dev/stdout
```

This approach however results in the error message:

```
ERR github.com/AlexxIT/go2rtc/internal/mjpeg/init.go:166 > error="streams: EOF"
```

What is the proper way to use a gstreamer input in go2rtc ?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever find out?